# Pandoc Error from Rmarkdown to PDF when centering plot

Tags: latex, pandoc, r-markdown

I'm receiving an error only when I include a centre option to the code chunk. My rmarkdown file looks like this:

````
```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width = 6, fig.height = 2.5, fig.align = "center"}

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
                geom_line(alpha=0.5) 

suppressWarnings(print(g))

```
````

I receive this message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.140 ...015_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-3-1}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

When I remove the `fig.align = "centre"` option it compiles with no error.

I'm using the `rmarkdown::render` function to convert from rmarkdown to PDF.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer but try including in the markdown file header keep_tex: true. Then you can examine the intermediate .tex file for clues in the vicinity of line 140

Comment: Alternatively, you could just do e.g. `pandoc input.md -o output.tex`. Examining the resulting .tex file is definitely useful. In my case, it helped me find that Pandoc was choking on a couple underscores found in a URL.